# The probability that x is larger than or equal to a given number

Tags: r, probability

I am working with the following data:

`x <- c(3.6, 3.7, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6, 1.2, 3.6)`

My task is to compute P(x≥2.5), but I cant seem to find the right code to calculate this. Other examples that I have found did not give me the right solution. Any pointers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to draw a random value y from `x`, then P(y >= 2.5) =
`sum(x >= 2.5)/length(x)`

Comment: Alternately `mean(x >= 2.5)`